# showing warning message in jot form

Tags: wordpress, jotform

I have a lightbox embed code for jot form and I need to show the warning message, if the user closes the lightbox before submitting the form, is it possible to do so? Please share any code to do so!

I have bronze plan and these options are not available in bronze plan.